# Automatically assign value into an object based on Enum Swift

Tags: swift, enums

so i have this object

```
class StationDetailsDTO: Object, Mappable {
    @objc dynamic var stateID = 0
    @objc dynamic var stateName = String()
}
```

This object will be assigned from API response object.

Now the problem is the API will just return stateID, without the stateName.

So what i want to achieve is, is there any possible way to automatically assign the stateName based on own-created Enum?

Because right now i am using normal if-else checking

```
If stateID == 0 {
 stateName = "A" 
}
else if stateID == 1 {
 stateName = "B"
}
```

I feel that this is not the best approach to implement. I am thinking of using Enum. I already created an Enum

```
enum State: String {
    case A 
    case B
    case C
}
```

I am thinking to use the case A(value), but not really sure how to implement it.

Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this? Or is there any other best approach that I could use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try `didSet` , and create an array of possible values

```
@objc dynamic var stateID = 0
{
    didSet {

        stateName = arr[stateID]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea Sir! So far this is the best approach I could use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to create an enum if you only intent to use it once, instead you can use a private func using switch statement during the initialization:

```
class StationDetailsDTO {

     private(set) var stateId: Int = 0
     private(set) var stateName: String = ""

     init(stateId: Int) {
         self.stateId = stateId
         self.stateName = initializeStateName()
     }

    private func initializeStateName() -> String {
        switch (self.stateId) {
            case 0: return "A"
            case 1: return "B"
            case 2: return "C"
            default : return ""
        }
    }
}

var test = StationDetailsDTO(stateId: 0)
print(test.stateName) // prints A
```